# What characteristics identify modified 'plant parts' as the respective 'plant parts'?

Tags: botany, morphology, homology

I was learning about different modifications in plant parts such as modified leaves, stems and roots from my [Biology textbook](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kebo105.pdf).

Modified parts differ as they are modified for different functions.

For example, the pitfall traps in a [pitcher plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcher_plant) are called modified leaves. These have completely different function than normal leaves but are still referred to be leaves.
[image]

**What characteristics identify such *parts* to be those *parts*?**

Comment: Not an answer but helpful background/vocabulary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(biology)